# Speeding up Monte Carlo simulations?

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration, simulation, montecarlo

I am currently doing research to predict where kudzu (an invasive vine) will spread in Oklahoma over a five year time by using Monte Carlo simulation. I have created a raster with presence points and loaded it into R.

For each Monte Carlo simulation (each year), I am running 6000 iterations to provide accurate results. However, due to "for" loops, this is taking a long time. The first year usually finishes running in 3 days, however the second year has been running for over 3 weeks and still is not complete.

Is there any way to speed this process up?

Each year builds off the previous one. I have provided the code below for the first two years:

```
OK.rast16<-raster("OK_rast20161.tif")
p.a16<-as.matrix(OK.rast16)
table(p.a16)

# Set the random number seed so results can be reproduced if needed
set.seed(10)

drow.pa16 <- 133.7197873 # distance of grid cell (meters) in n-s direction
trow.pa16 <- length(p.a16[,1]) # total number of rows

dcol.pa16 <- 133.7197873 # distance of grid cell (meters) in e-w direction
tcol.pa16 <- length(p.a16[1,]) # total number of rows

#####Year 1 of infection in 2016#####

kudzu_sim1_16 <- matrix(0,trow.pa16,tcol.pa16)
for(m in 1:6000)
{
  OK.kudzu_16 <- p.a16 # initialize matrix of annual dispersal
  for(i in 1:trow.pa16)
{
  for(j in 1:tcol.pa16)
{
  if(!is.na(p.a16[i,j]) & p.a16[i,j] == 1)
  {
    for(k in 1:trow.pa16)
    {
      for(l in 1:tcol.pa16)
      {
        if(!is.na(OK.kudzu_16[k,l]) & OK.kudzu_16[k,l] == 0)
        {
          distcalc <- sqrt((abs(i-k)*drow.pa16)^2+(abs(j-l)*dcol.pa16)^2)
          prob <- exp(0.0369599-0.00474401*distcalc)
          if(prob>runif(1)) {OK.kudzu_16[k,l] <- 1}
        }
      }
    }
   }
  }
 }
 kudzu_sim1_16 <- OK.kudzu_16+kudzu_sim1_16
}

#####Year 2 of infection in 2016####

kudzu_sim2_16 <- matrix(0,trow.pa16,tcol.pa16)
for(m in 1:6000)
{
  OK.kudzu1_16 <- OK.kudzu_16 # initialize matrix of annual dispersal
   for(i in 1:trow.pa16)
  {
    for(j in 1:tcol.pa16)
   {
     if(!is.na(OK.kudzu_16[i,j]) & OK.kudzu_16[i,j] == 1)
  {
    for(k in 1:trow.pa16)
    {
      for(l in 1:tcol.pa16)
      {
        if(!is.na(OK.kudzu1_16[k,l]) & OK.kudzu1_16[k,l] == 0)
        {
          distcalc <- sqrt((abs(i-k)*drow.pa16)^2+(abs(j-l)*dcol.pa16)^2)
          prob <- exp(0.0369599-0.00474401*distcalc)
          if(prob>runif(1)) {OK.kudzu1_16[k,l] <- 1}
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
kudzu_sim2_16 <- OK.kudzu1_16+kudzu_sim2_16
}
```

Here is the raster to load to start the code:

[kudzu in OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW7mU.png)

Comment: I think this might belong on codereview instead because code is working. Also if you can shorten your post and example  and follow coding standards (for easier code reading) you might be more likely to get useful answers

Comment: The image that you posted can't be the actual raster that you are using (given your grid size). What are the values of `dcol.pa16` and `tcol.pa16`? The link that you give is to an image file which is just 250x518 pixels and Oklahoma is much wider than 518 * 133 meters.

Comment: @JohnColeman I just realized that as well. I changed the grid size to 1500mx1500m.

Comment: When I run your setup code with the downloaded file file I get an array that consists almost entirely of `0` and `255` (with some stray `1` corresponding to random pixels in Texas) rather than `0` and `1`. Furthermore, there seems to be nothing that corresponds to kudzu data.  Also, the `is.na()` checks seem pointless since the array has no `NA` entries. If your `p.a16` consists of `0`, `1` and `NA`, then you have not provided a way for others to reproduce the problem. Without a [mcve] it is hard to say much.

Answer (score 0):

Originally a comment, but it rapidly exceeded the length limit:

1) 133mx133m is a very small grid size for spatial simulations on something as large as an entire state. It might help to find a way to make resolution a parameter of your simulation (rather than a hard-wired number), streamline the code so that it runs well at a larger resolution, then increase the resolution. The `raster` function has an optional parameter named `res` which can be used to control the resolution.

2) While vectorization will surely help, it is unlikely to transform an algorithm which runs for weeks with no output into one which runs in a reasonable amount of time. Perhaps you need to fundamentally rethink your algorithm. You seem to be comparing every grid cell with every other grid cell. That doesn't strike me as biologically plausible. Kudzu spreads locally. Why should what happens next year to a given 133m x 133m cell in the Oklahoma panhandle depend on the current state of another cell over by Lake Texoma? If your simulation has any biological realism, `exp(0.0369599-0.00474401*distcalc)` should be negligibly small for two such cells, but your code doesn't neglect it. An algorithm which is in some sense localized might be better.

3) There is an awful lot of entries in your matrix which correspond to points outside of Oklahoma. Unless your model is designed to see how kudzu also diffuses over a large part of Texas, those might be irrelevant for your program. If so, a fundamentally different data structure (e.g. a list of locations) which only has entries for points in Oklahoma might be preferable. Or, maybe not. Just something to think about.

4) For more detailed help, it would help if you explain what your algorithm actually is (and not just what it intends to do). It isn't completely obvious in a quick read of your code.

Comment: Thank you for the comments/suggestions. How can the code be localized? Or does that have to be done below the simulations?

Also, the algorithm is that the initial matrix (with kudzu presences) in used as an input. The simulation goes through each cell. If there is kudzu in one cell, it moves to the next cell. If a cell is empty, a couple of calculations occur. The distance between that empty cell and all cells are then calculated. That distance is then entered into the probability equation. If the probability is greater than one, that once empty cell now equals 1 and kudzu is present there.